# Нужна ли здесь запятая после "это"?

Tags: запятые, спп

Играли долго и нудно, Сэн даже и не думала, что сможет обыграть Ооноки, и поняла это лишь когда внук Цучикаге тихо выругался и сбросил карты, с ненавистью смотря на Учиху.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обязательно. Она ставится, как говорится, вопреки интонации. Она называется не "после это", а перед "лишь когда".

> **[Частица «лишь»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_395)** может стоять перед союзом в сложноподчиненном предложении. В этом случае запятая перед частицей «лишь» ставится, а
>   между «лишь» и союзом отсутствует.
>
> *Сомневаться в существовании действительности мы можем, **лишь когда** не спим.* А. Генис, Темнота и тишина. *Но армию любят, **лишь если**
>   идет война.* С. Лукьяненко, Ночной дозор.

Уточняющее правило, с другими примерами:

[ЛИШЬ(,) КОГДА, частица + союзное слово](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=1341)

(Смотреть у Розенталя: [§ 34 п. 6](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=172#ppp_6). Смотреть [в справочнике РАН: § 116](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=346#pp346))

> Выделяется запятыми придаточное предложение, присоединяемое союзным
>   словом 'когда'. При этом запятая ставится перед частицей 'лишь', а
>   перед 'когда' знак препинания не требуется.
>
> *Они могут снова что-то значить, **лишь когда** канет то, с чем они полностью совпали.* А. Битов, Записки гоя.
>
> Однако запятая перед союзным словом 'когда' ставится, если словам
>   'лишь когда' предшествует указательное местоимение 'тогда' (образуется
>   конструкция 'тогда лишь, когда').
>
> *Но беда в том была, что белесые языки эти к озерам ползли, а он, наоборот, к лесу норовил фрицев вывести и поэтому нырял в туман
>   **тогда лишь, когда** уж совсем невмоготу становилось.* Б. Васильев, А зори здесь тихие.